# name lookup timed out - Cannot find solution

Tags: wordpress, curl, authentication

I am working on a local MAMP server, I have a vhost running my site at http://local.mysite.com on a WordPress Install

I am using the JS SDK to log the user in on the front end, and then I am posting to the REST API the access token I am receiving from the JS Login request...

My endpoint has the following:

```
$data = $request->get_json_params();

$expires = time() + (60 * DAY_IN_SECONDS);
$access_token = new Facebook\Authentication\AccessToken( $data['accessToken'], $expires );

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    'app_secret' => FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
    'default_access_token' => $access_token,
]);

wp_send_json($fb->get('/me'));
exit;
```

But whenever I run this I am getting

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException: name lookup timed out in /Users/ldewitt/Development/site/wp-content/themes/mysite/includes/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php:73

I have searched the site, and everything I am seeing is telling me to up the timeout limit, but doing that just delays when I see the error. I feel like I am very close right now, but obviously something is wrong... can anyone please help me out?

Thanks,

--d

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution... was quite simple...

Because I was working locally and my site was not over HTTPS, the call was failing... I switched this setting in "FacebookCurlHttpClient" and it worked immediately.

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
```

Thanks to anyone who took some time to look!

--d